# Setting Background image of button as a Image view Image

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'v an application in which i want to set the image of my image view same as my button, which is been clicked..
i'm using this code;

```
mainSlideShowImageView.image=((UIButton *)sender).image;
```

but there is Error..

**65: error: request for member 'image' in something not a structure or union**

what is other way to do So?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[(UIButton *)sender imageForState:UIControlStateNormal];`

or, if it's a background image, `backgroundImageForState:`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using currentImage or currentBackgroundImage like so:

```
UIButton *ad = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
UIImageView *iV = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:ad.currentBackgroundImage];
```

or

```
UIButton *ad = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
UIImageView *iV = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:ad.currentImage];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
mainSlideShowImageView.image= button.currentImage;
```